# Why bigText doesn't return Style type

Tags: android, notifications, styles

Why bigText() method doesn't return Style type inside setStyle 
Or why setStyle requires Style Type ?

see the image

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BRYjh4OQp83-VcFmcRjXQpU798asu-16

I am trying to make a notification

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "kdfjds", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this);

    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    notification.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
    notification.setContentTitle("order");
    notification.setContentText("You have new order");

    Intent goToOrder = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,97,goToOrder,0);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notification.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(this.getString(R.string.charging_reminder_notification_title)));
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }
    }



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Notification.BigTextStyle()` instead of `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()`.

P.S - The issue here is that you're trying to mix up packages, you're essentially trying to use `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` when `android.app.Notification.Style` is expected.

Comment: But I changed import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle to  import android.app.Notification.Style and I used NotificationCompat but still the problem exist with NotificationCompat

Comment: `NotificationCompat` is a class contained in the `android.support.v4.app` package. You can use `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` if you use `NotificationCompat` everywhere.

Comment: The support libraries are for backward compatibility with the earlier versions of android.

Comment: I figured that 
  Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this);
should be 
  Notification.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
to use NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle
I also sloved the problem by changing the builder from Notification to NotificationCompat so that NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle can be used